# search function in mongoDB with case-insensitive query

Tags: mongodb, case-insensitive

I am doing with function in mongoDB, now it's have problem with case-insensitive data. this is my code in function

```
$where = array(TblFact::Fou_Name => array('$regex' =>$SearchNameFactory));
```

this code when data in uppercase and i search by lowercase is return null. So anyone can help me to find solution for case-insensitive query ? 
I am looking to see your replay soon. Thanks ...

Comment: That question's answer promotes bad practice. Don't use a case-insensitive query for this, because that query will **not make use of indexes** and will hence require a full collection scan. For large collections, that takes ages.

Normalize the names instead, i.e. allow only all-lowercase names.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks everyone for help me , now my problem have been resolve by

```
 $where = array(TblFact::Fou_Name => new MongoRegex("{$SearchNameFactory}/i"));
```

hope it can help to anyone who meet problem like me

thanks